# Separating .txt file with Python

Tags: python, file, txt

I have to separate .txt file into small pieces, based on the matched value. For example, I have .txt file looks like:

```
Names Age Country
Mark 19 USA
John 19 UK
Elon 20 CAN
Dominic 21 USA
Andreas 21 UK
```

I have to extract all rows with the same value “Age” and to copy them to other file or perfom some other action..

How it is possible to be done with Python, I have never do that before.

Thank you in advance :)

I am asking, because of I have no idea how it should be done. The excpected result is to have this data separated:

```
Names Age Country
Mark 19 USA
John 19 UK

Names Age Country
Elon 20 CAN

Names Age Country
Dominic 21 USA
Andreas 21 UK
```

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: I suggest breaking this down into small pieces. First, open the file and read the entire contents. Then read each line one at a time. Then split up each line into pieces. Just take it one step at a time until you figure out enough to finish the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```py
with open('yourfile.txt') as infile:
    header = next(infile)
    ages = {}

    for line in infile:
        name, age, country = line.rsplit(' ', 2)
        if age not in ages:
            ages[age] = []
        ages[age].append([name, age, country])

    for age in ages:
        with open(f'age-{age}.txt', 'w') as agefile:
             agefile.writeline(header)  
             agefile.writelines(ages[age])
```

For the sample you posted, the code above will leave you with files named `age-19.txt`, `age-20.txt`, and `age-21.txt`, with the contents separated by age, as you requested.

Answer (score -1):

If you have them all in a list you can use something like this...

```
alltext = ["Names Age Country", "Mark 21 USA", "John 21 UK","Elon 20 CAN","Dominic 21 USA", "Andreas 21 UK"]

Canada = [alltext[0]] #Creates a list with your column header
NotCanada = [alltext[0]] #Creates a list with your column header

for row in alltext[1:]:
    x = row.split()
    if x[2] == "CAN":
        Canada.append(row)
    else:
        NotCanada.append(row)

print(Canada)
print(NotCanada)
```

Will print two different lists of your separated players.

['Names Age Country', 'Elon 20 CAN']

['Names Age Country', 'Mark 21 USA', 'John 21 UK', 'Dominic 21 USA', 'Andreas 21 UK']

Comment: This solution doesn't read the data in from a file or output the data to files as the @wrangler requested.

Comment: Looks like the question was rewritten while I was answering it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).